# Laravel 5.3 blank page with wrong authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a page where I login my user. The page is pretty much straight forward. When I try with the correct username/password it returns me to the view I want to, but on invalid combo I land on a blank white page. Any help on this would be appreciated.

**login.blade.php:**

```
<form action="{{ route('submitlogin') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        @if($errors->has('username'))
            <label class="control-label" for="username"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> {{ $errors->first('username') }}</label>
        @endif
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" value="{{ Request::old('username') }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        @if($errors->has('password'))
            <label class="control-label" for="password"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> {{ $errors->first('password') }}</label>
        @endif
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**web.php(routes):**

```
Route::post('/home', [
            'uses' => 'SigninSignupController@postSubmitLogin',
            'as' => 'submitlogin'
    ]);
```

**SigninSignupController.php:**

```
public function postSubmitLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'username' => 'required|alpha|max:20|min:4',
                'password' => 'required|max:20|min:7'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            return view('pages.welcome');
        }
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `else` to your `if (Auth::attempt)` line.
Something like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
    return view('pages.welcome');
} else {
    // user is not valid, redirect back to login here
    session()->flash('alert', 'Bad Credentials');
    return view('pages.login');
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't it return to the existing view even if the auth::attempt fails? Also, is there any way I can show the error without using the session flash? I mean using laravel's existing $errors variable is it possible?

Comment: @JackSlayer94 The `Auth::attempt()` method returns true on success and false on failure. It's up to you to determine what to do with that. The `$errors` variable is typically used for validating user input from forms and displaying what needs to be corrected.